# Sporadic speedometer, and performance lags when speedometer not engaged

Tags: electrical, repair, sensor, performance, speedometer

I have a 2000 Honda Accord, 2.3L L4 with a 5-speed manual transmission. Recently, the speedometer has been sporadic- sometimes accurate, sometimes bouncing around, but mostly sitting at 0. I replaced my VSS, which seemed to help, but only a week or so after I installed it. It works more consistently now. There is a noticeable increase in performance when the speedometer engages compared to when it sits at 0.

Any tips?

Comment: Are you absolutely certain that there is marked difference? Could it be that you're imaging it?

Comment: Do you happen to have an ABS light on?

Comment: No ABS ligth. And no, I'm not imagining it. In fact, I noticed it was related because whenever I felt a sudden increase in power, I glanced down and saw the speedometer needle swinging up into position. However, now I noticed power increases when the speedometer is swaying back and forth also. I'm beginning to think there's a bigger problem that is effecting both the speedometer and engine performance at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

The Vehicle Speed Sensor sends signal to the Instrument Cluster.

You can check pin 2 (blue/white) on the B connector for signal from the VSS. If there is signal you need a new cluster. If not you have to check continuity between the cluster and VSS

Comment: It's a manual transmission

Comment: @Zaid Ah my bad, reading is hard. It's still the same pin/wire color it just bypasses the ECM.

Comment: @Ben thanks for the info. I'm starting to think it's not a problem with the speedometer or cluster, though. I've noticed that the increase/decrease in performance is not strictly tied to whether the speedometer is working or not, but neither one starts acting up without the other following. Any advice for this? What could effect both simultaneously?

Comment: @JonathanPetry Hmm, both operate on ignition voltage. So I'd suggest monitoring ignition voltage while this is happening maybe the voltage regulator is acting up on the alternator and with the sensors seeing too much voltage start to act weird. Or the ground side of the circuit is intermittent. When it acts up while testing ignition voltage you can also voltage drop test the engine grounds by placing one lead on the battery negative terminal and the other on a ground point at the engine anything over 0.25mV would suggest a bad engine ground or bad frame to battery ground.

Comment: @Ben good to know. I'm somewhat inexperienced in the greater details of how cars work; I noticed recently that my alternator belt is in prime condition to be replaced. It is very cracked, and has started to make noise when I start the vehicle. Is it possible that the belt is slipping? Would that cause a similar issue?

Comment: @JonathanPetry it could be but unlikely unless the battery isnt holding a charge and ignition voltage was sub 12v